# R Shiny How to access slider min & max values in server code

Tags: r, slider, shiny

Is there a way to reference the minimum & maximum values of a slider within the `server.R` portion of a Shiny app?

For instance, given the following definition within `ui.R`:

```
sliderInput("slider1", "", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50)
```

how do I determine that the preset minimum is 0, and the maximum  is 100?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the min and max values when you access them.  I assume that you don't want to just read them, since you would already know their fixed values.  If you want to be able to manipulate them, you could try defining the slider in `server.R` using `renderUI`.  Then you could set the `min` and `max` parameters to variables, which could be manipulated elsewhere.  Below is an example of that.

## ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Access the min and max of a slider"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("SliderWidget")),
    mainPanel()
  )
))
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  SlideMax = 100
  SlideMin = 0
  output$SliderWidget <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("Slider1","",min = SlideMin,max = SlideMax,value = 50)
  })
})
```

Of course, your question actually asks how to determine the preset values.  I'm not sure I understand that.  I think that the preset values would be static, so there would be no need to determine them.

Comment: Thanks.

Actually, I did just want to read them :)

I was trying to keep some independence between the ui & server elements. But thanks to your suggestion I can still do that, driving the values from the server side.

An alternative would be to have a common include file containing static definitions that is read by both source files.

Answer (score 0):

I've now found that one can have a third file as part of a shiny app, called `global.R`.

So, for the use case above I could define the min and max parameters as constants in the `global.R` file or dynamically create the slider as per Paul's suggestion.